# My android application suddenly stopped working

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been bugged by this problem and I got to make a quick fix to this. Please help me. So currently im experiencing crashes everytime I paste some new codes that I find online. [P.S. Im a newb in android programming]

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="birada1.tulungatung.ph.myapplication2">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/chess_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I made some minor changes to `MainActivity.java`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    one.setOnClickListener(this);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);
    three.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.button2:
            Intent intenthistory = new Intent(this, ChessHistoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(intenthistory);
            // do your code
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            Intent intenthistory2 = new Intent(this, LearnChessActivity.class);
            startActivity(intenthistory2);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            Intent intenthistory3 = new Intent(this, GrandmastersActivity.class);
            startActivity(intenthistory3);
            break;


        default:
    }

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img_view3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="95dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/hellow"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/boom" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:onClick="btnClick1"
android:text="@string/c_history" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img_view4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="101dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/hellow"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/chess_moves_three" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="btnClick2"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:text="@string/c_moves" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView5"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="113dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/hellow"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/grandmasters" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button4"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:onClick="btnClick3"
android:text="@string/c_grandmasters" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check the red logs and post here.

Comment: add your activity to your manifest.. its crash because of intent activity is not registered yet

Answer (score 1):

Remove your application tag from manifest and paste this application tag and try it your problem will be solved.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/chess_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ChessHistoryActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".LearnChessActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".GrandmastersActivity"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared ChessHistoryActivity / LearnChessActivity / GrandmastersActivity in AndroidManifest.xml ?
if not add

```
<activity android:name=".ChessHistoryActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTask" />

<activity android:name=".LearnChessActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTask" />

<activity android:name=".GrandmastersActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First add `ChessHistoryActivity.java`, `LearnChessActivity.java` and `GrandmastersActivity.java` classes into your java `source` Folder`(If not added yet)`.

   **Folder:**  `./app/src/main/java/birada1.tulungatung.ph.myapplication2/`
2. Declare `ChessHistoryActivity`, `LearnChessActivity` and `GrandmastersActivity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       package="birada1.tulungatung.ph.myapplication2">

       <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@mipmap/chess_icon"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
           android:supportsRtl="true"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

           <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>

           <activity android:name=".ChessHistoryActivity" />
           <activity android:name=".LearnChessActivity" />
           <activity android:name=".GrandmastersActivity" />

       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```

Hope this will help~